# import_id parameter for wp_insert_term to create custom ID for category

Tags: terms

Is there an option to create a category with a custom ID, like a custom post ID is created using the parameter `import_id`?

```
$post = array(
    'post_title'   => 'whatever',
    'post_content' => 'whatever',
    'import_id'    => 123
);
wp_insert_post( $post );
```

What I want to do is create a custom post type using `wp_insert_post` and will import data from a table which has a category ID attached.

So I want to create categories with custom IDs that are attached to a products table.

Right now I'm using a custom field added to categories as `OLD_CATEGORY_ID` and get posts against this custom field ID.

Categories are also imported to WordPress.

Is there a better way, or is this the only way? :)

Comment: is my question is too difficult for experts ? or it is not clear ? :)